# Finding stats for data in PostgreSQL table. Unique count and highest frequency per column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to know some values for every table column, and hoping to be able to do so in one query.

Let's imagine we have a table with columns: A, B, C.

```
A     B      C
--------------------
Red   Red    Red
Red   Blue   Red
Blue  Green  Red
Blue  Green  Red
```

I'd like an output that says how many unique values for A, B and C as individual columns.
So, it would give out

```
2, 3, 1
```

- 2 unique values for A(Red and Blue)
- 3 unique values for B(Red, Blue and Green)
- 1 unique value for C(Red)

Is there anyway to get this in a single call.

Also, I'd like to get the frequency of the most common value:

```
2, 2, 4
```

- 2 because there's 2 red(or blue, same value),
- 2 because there's 2 green,
- 4 because there's 4 red

In the same or another query.

I don't want to do a separate query for each column, because there may be a lot of columns in theory.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: In the first example, shouldn't the result be `2, 3, 1` instead of `2, 3, 4`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How many unique values are there for each column using [`aggregate functiions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) & [`DISTINCT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):**

```
select
  count(distinct a) as cnt_a,
  count(distinct b) as cnt_b,
  count(distinct c) as cnt_c
from yourtable
```

Returns:

```
2,3,1
```

**Frequency of the most common value using [`window functions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) & [`aggregate functiions`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):**

```
select 
  max(cnt_a) as fr_a,
  max(cnt_b) as fr_b,
  max(cnt_c) as fr_c
from (
  select
    count(*) over (partition by a) as cnt_a,
    count(*) over (partition by b) as cnt_b,
    count(*) over (partition by c) as cnt_c
  from yourtable
) t
```

Returns:

```
2,2,4
```

**Combined together with [`UNION ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html)**:

```
select
  'unique values' as description,
  count(distinct a) as cnt_a,
  count(distinct b) as cnt_b,
  count(distinct c) as cnt_c
from yourtable
union all
select
  'freq of most common value',
  max(cnt_a),
  max(cnt_b),
  max(cnt_c)
from (
  select
    count(*) over (partition by a) as cnt_a,
    count(*) over (partition by b) as cnt_b,
    count(*) over (partition by c) as cnt_c
  from yourtable
) t
```

Returns:

```
        description        | cnt_a | cnt_b | cnt_c
---------------------------+-------+-------+-------
 unique values             |     2 |     3 |     1
 freq of most common value |     2 |     2 |     4
```

Comment: I was struggling with the second one. Upvoting.

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks. I'm not sure this is the best way to approach this, but thought of using window functions for that :-)

Comment: Additionally: If you want to find the most frequent value (not its count) you can use: `SELECT mode() WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a) FROM data`